# Trying to convert timestamp from twitter api into DateTime in flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, twitter

To make it more understandable:
From Twitter API you will get String Date in this format (Thu Mar 26 11:51:30 +0000 2020)
All i want to do is make this String parse with DateTime format so i need to change the format from this (Thu Mar 26 11:51:30 +0000 2020) to something like this (26.04.2020 11:51:30), is this somehow possible ? Thank you :)

Comment: do you just want to print date time or you also want to store anywhere else? moreover, what exactly you want?

Comment: i want to store it as DateTime format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use substring method of string and cut each and every part then pass all that in datetime.

I hope Following code solve your issue.

```
  int month;
  String datetime = "Thu Mar 26 11:51:30 +0000 2020";
  String monthInString = datetime.substring(4, 7);
  int day = int.parse(datetime.substring(8, 10));
  int hours = int.parse(datetime.substring(11, 13));
  int min = int.parse(datetime.substring(14, 16));
  int second = int.parse(datetime.substring(17, 19));
  int year = int.parse(datetime.substring(26, 30));
  DateTime _dateTime;
  switch (monthInString) {
    // add all months
    case 'Jan':
      month = 1;
      break;
    case 'Mar':
      month = 3;
      break;
  }
  _dateTime = DateTime.utc(year, month, day, hours, min, second);
  print(_dateTime);
```

Comment: That's looking promising, thanks a lot. I'll try when i come home.